# Forward std::unique_ptr via lambda into a function

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, unique-ptr

I have an class `job`. I want to create a unique_ptr of job, capture it in a lamdba and execute a function in a lambda which forwards this pointer:

The function:

```
void printJob(std::unique_ptr<job> aJob)
```

Lamdba:

```
auto jobptr = std::make_unique<job>(<arguments>);

auto function = [this, j = std::move(jobptr)]
{
    printJob(j);
};
```

The `function` is executed on a different thread therefor the lamdba is used
The `j` argument in the lamdba is of type `std::remove_reference_t<std::unique_ptr<job> &>` while the function need a `std::unique_ptr<job>`. Can I make this work? Tried options with `std::move` and `std::forward` but I cant get it to compile. I am using C++14.

I have found alternatives (shared_ptr, raw pointer, etc) but this is more in sync with the existing code.

Comment: If you don't need dynamic polymorphism (virtual function calls) why not just use `job ajob{<arguments>};` and have a move constructor on job and the move job into j? Try to use the minimum complexity needed to get the job done (pun intended).

Comment: The job is an interface and therefore this cannot work

Comment: please show a [mre] and include the error message you're encountering. A function called `print` which takes ownership of `aJob` seems unusual?

Comment: @Eric Then using std::unique_ptr is totally fine :) 
If the function only requires a non-owning pointer and you can manage the life cycle of the job so it lasts longer then the function call then just pass a raw pointer (or reference if pointer can never be null). Passing a non-owning raw pointer to functions is still ok.

Answer (score 1):

If `printJob`'s parameter is a `std::unique_ptr<job>` then it must be passed in via move semantics, via `std::move` itself.

Captured objects in regular lambdas are, effectively, `const` object, hence they are not movable. The solution is simple: use a mutable lambda.

```
auto function = [this, j = std::move(jobptr)]
mutable {
    printJob(std::move(j));
};
```

It goes without saying that this lambda can only be effectively executed just once.

But does `printJob` really need to take ownership of the passed in parameter? If not, if it's just as happy as

```
void printJob(const std::unique_ptr<job> &aJob)
```

then none of this is needed.

Comment: The function is executed only once on a single thread. Mutable keyword solved the this issue. The printjob function has to take ownership since it the printjob since it must becoe inaccessible